# how to add multiprocessing to loops?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, loops, multiprocessing

I have a large customer data set (10 million+) , that I am running my loop calculation. I am trying to add multiprocessing, but it seems to take longer when I use multiprocessing, by splitting data1 into chunks running it in sagemaker studio. I am not sure what I am doing wrong but the calculation takes longer when using multiprocessing, please help.

input data example:

```
state_list = ['A','B','C','D','E'] #possible states

data1 = pd.DataFrame({"cust_id": ['x111','x112'], #customer data
                    "state": ['B','E'],
                    "amount": [1000,500],
                    "year":[3,2],
                    "group":[10,10],
                    "loan_rate":[0.12,0.13]})

data1['state'] = pd.Categorical(data1['state'], 
                                        categories=state_list, 
                                        ordered=True).codes


lookup1 = pd.DataFrame({'year': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
                    'lim %': [0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1,0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1]}).set_index(['year'])

matrix_data = np.arange(250).reshape(10,5,5) #3d matrix by state(A-E) and year(1-10)

end = pd.Timestamp(year=2021, month=9, day=1)    # creating a list of dates
df = pd.DataFrame({"End": pd.date_range(end, periods=10, freq="M")})
df['End']=df['End'].dt.day
End=df.values
end_dates = End.reshape(-1)  # array([30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30]); just to simplify access to the end date values
```

calculation:

```
num_processes = 4
# Split the customer data into chunks
chunks = np.array_split(data1, num_processes)
queue = mp.Queue()

def calc(chunk):
    results1={}
    for cust_id, state, amount, start, group, loan_rate in chunks.itertuples(name=None, index=False):
        res1 = [amount * matrix_data[start-1, state, :]]
        for year in range(start+1, len(matrix_data)+1,):
            res1.append(lookup1.loc[year].iat[0] * np.array(res1[-1]))
            res1.append(res1[-1] * loan_rate * end_dates[year-1]/365) # year - 1 here
            res1.append(res1[-1]+ 100)
            res1.append(np.linalg.multi_dot([res1[-1],matrix_data[year-1]]))
        results1[cust_id] = res1 
    queue.put(results1)

processes = [mp.Process(target=calc, args=(chunk,)) for chunk in chunks]

for p in processes:
    p.start()

for p in processes:
    p.join()

results1 = {}
while not queue.empty():
    results1.update(queue.get())
```

Comment: Where is *process_chunk* defined and what does it do? Also looks like your indentation may be flawed (see *queue.put(results1)*)

Comment: @Fred thanks for assisting, process_chunk is a typo, target=calc.I have fixed the indentation, any help will be greatly appreciated multiprocessing is confusing to newbies like me

Comment: (1) The test `queue.empty()` for a `multiprocessing.Queue` instance is not reliable and should not be used. (2) You must never issue `queue.get()` *after* having joined the processes that have put elements on the queue or else suffer a possible deadlock. Multiprocessing only improves performance if your worker function `calc` is sufficiently CPU-intensive to offset the additional overhead that multiprocessing entails. Your code will also never run under an OS that uses *spawn* to create new processes (e..g. Windows).

Comment: @Booboo how can i fix this?

Comment: If you have N child processes each putting one item on the queue, then you know there should be N items to get. So you do blocking `get` calls until you have retrieved N items and only then do you `join` the child processes. If each child process put an indeterminate number of items on the queue, then each child needs to put a special *sentinel* item as the last one that signifies there are no more items that they will be putting. This is any instance that cannot be mistaken for an actual data item, for example `None`. You then do blocking `get` calls until you have seen `N` sentinels.

Comment: You have `for cust_id, state, amount, start, group, loan_rate in chunks.itertuples(name=None, index=False):`. But shouldn't that be `for cust_id, state, amount, start, group, loan_rate in chunk.itertuples(name=None, index=False):`, i.e. `chunk.itertuples` insead of `chunks.itertuples`? Also, what is the actual number rows in `data1` (approximately)?

Comment: @Booboo yes chunk instead of chunks, sorry this is my first time using multiprocessing and I'm finding it difficult to understand. data1 is my customer data that has 10m + rows.

Comment: In your attempt to simplify your code, you have left out some important details. First, when you say "10m" you mean 10 thousand (10K) and not 10 million (10mm), right? And I assume you are loading it all into memory from a file, right?

Comment: @Booboo it's 10 million customers, I am currently running my calculation on a test set of 100k, in sagemaker.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251077/discussion-between-booboo-and-user1000x).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it would be easier to use a multiprocessing pool with the `map` method, which will submit tasks in chunks anyway but your worker function `calc` just needs to deal with individuals tuples since the chunking is done in a transparent function. The pool will compute what it thinks is an optimal number of rows to be chunked together based on the total number of rows and the number of processes in the pool, but you can override this. So a solution would look something like the following. Since you have not tagged your question with the OS you are running under, the code below should run under Windows, Linux or MacOS in the most efficient way for that platform. But as I mentioned in a comment, multiprocessing may actually slow down getting your results if `calc` is not sufficiently CPU-intensive.

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def init_pool_processes(*args):
    global lookup1, matrix_data, end_dates
    lookup1, matrix_data, end_dates = args # unpack

def calc(t):
    cust_id, state, amount, start, group, loan_rate = t # unpack
    results1 = {}
    res1 = [amount * matrix_data[start-1, state, :]]
    for year in range(start+1, len(matrix_data)+1,):
        res1.append(lookup1.loc[year].iat[0] * np.array(res1[-1]))
        res1.append(res1[-1] * loan_rate * end_dates[year-1]/365) # year - 1 here
        res1.append(res1[-1] + 100)
    return (cust_id, res1) # return tuple

def main():
    state_list = ['A','B','C','D','E'] #possible states

    data1 = pd.DataFrame({"cust_id": ['x111','x112'], #customer data
                        "state": ['B','E'],
                        "amount": [1000,500],
                        "year":[3,2],
                        "group":[10,10],
                        "loan_rate":[0.12,0.13]})

    data1['state'] = pd.Categorical(data1['state'],
                                            categories=state_list,
                                            ordered=True).codes

    lookup1 = pd.DataFrame({'year': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
                        'lim %': [0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1,0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1]}).set_index(['year'])

    matrix_data = np.arange(250).reshape(10,5,5) #3d matrix by state(A-E) and year(1-10)

    end = pd.Timestamp(year=2021, month=9, day=1)    # creating a list of dates
    df = pd.DataFrame({"End": pd.date_range(end, periods=10, freq="M")})
    df['End']=df['End'].dt.day
    End=df.values
    end_dates = End.reshape(-1)  # array([30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30]); just to simplify access to the end date values

    with Pool(initializer=init_pool_processes, initargs=(lookup1, matrix_data, end_dates)) as pool:
        results = {cust_id: arr for cust_id, arr in pool.map(calc, data1.itertuples(name=None, index=False))}
    for cust_id, arr in results.items():
        print(cust_id, arr)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Prints:

```None
x111 [array([55000, 56000, 57000, 58000, 59000]), array([5500., 5600., 5700., 5800., 5900.]), array([56.05479452, 57.0739726 , 58.09315068, 59.11232877, 60.13150685]), array([156.05479452, 157.0739726 , 158.09315068, 159.11232877,
       160.13150685]), array([15.60547945, 15.70739726, 15.80931507, 15.91123288, 16.01315068]), array([0.15904763, 0.16008635, 0.16112507, 0.1621638 , 0.16320252]), array([100.15904763, 100.16008635, 100.16112507, 100.1621638 ,
       100.16320252]), array([10.01590476, 10.01600864, 10.01611251, 10.01621638, 10.01632025]), array([0.09220121, 0.09220216, 0.09220312, 0.09220407, 0.09220503]), array([100.09220121, 100.09220216, 100.09220312, 100.09220407,
       100.09220503]), array([10.00922012, 10.00922022, 10.00922031, 10.00922041, 10.0092205 ]), array([0.10201178, 0.10201178, 0.10201178, 0.10201178, 0.10201178]), array([100.10201178, 100.10201178, 100.10201178, 100.10201178,
       100.10201178]), array([10.01020118, 10.01020118, 10.01020118, 10.01020118, 10.01020118]), array([0.09873075, 0.09873075, 0.09873075, 0.09873075, 0.09873075]), array([100.09873075, 100.09873075, 100.09873075, 100.09873075,
       100.09873075]), array([10.00987308, 10.00987308, 10.00987308, 10.00987308, 10.00987308]), array([0.10201843, 0.10201843, 0.10201843, 0.10201843, 0.10201843]), array([100.10201843, 100.10201843, 100.10201843, 100.10201843,
       100.10201843]), array([10.01020184, 10.01020184, 10.01020184, 10.01020184, 10.01020184]), array([0.09873076, 0.09873076, 0.09873076, 0.09873076, 0.09873076]), array([100.09873076, 100.09873076, 100.09873076, 100.09873076,
       100.09873076])]
x112 [array([22500, 23000, 23500, 24000, 24500]), array([2250., 2300., 2350., 2400., 2450.]), array([24.04109589, 24.57534247, 25.10958904, 25.64383562, 26.17808219]), array([124.04109589, 124.57534247, 125.10958904, 125.64383562,
       126.17808219]), array([12.40410959, 12.45753425, 12.5109589 , 12.56438356, 12.61780822]), array([0.13695496, 0.13754483, 0.1381347 , 0.13872456, 0.13931443]), array([100.13695496, 100.13754483, 100.1381347 , 100.13872456,
       100.13931443]), array([10.0136955 , 10.01375448, 10.01381347, 10.01387246, 10.01393144]), array([0.11056217, 0.11056282, 0.11056347, 0.11056413, 0.11056478]), array([100.11056217, 100.11056282, 100.11056347, 100.11056413,
       100.11056478]), array([10.01105622, 10.01105628, 10.01105635, 10.01105641, 10.01105648]), array([0.09983629, 0.09983629, 0.09983629, 0.09983629, 0.09983629]), array([100.09983629, 100.09983629, 100.09983629, 100.09983629,
       100.09983629]), array([10.00998363, 10.00998363, 10.00998363, 10.00998363, 10.00998363]), array([0.11052119, 0.11052119, 0.11052119, 0.11052119, 0.11052119]), array([100.11052119, 100.11052119, 100.11052119, 100.11052119,
       100.11052119]), array([10.01105212, 10.01105212, 10.01105212, 10.01105212, 10.01105212]), array([0.10696741, 0.10696741, 0.10696741, 0.10696741, 0.10696741]), array([100.10696741, 100.10696741, 100.10696741, 100.10696741,
       100.10696741]), array([10.01069674, 10.01069674, 10.01069674, 10.01069674, 10.01069674]), array([0.11052906, 0.11052906, 0.11052906, 0.11052906, 0.11052906]), array([100.11052906, 100.11052906, 100.11052906, 100.11052906,
       100.11052906]), array([10.01105291, 10.01105291, 10.01105291, 10.01105291, 10.01105291]), array([0.10696741, 0.10696741, 0.10696741, 0.10696741, 0.10696741]), array([100.10696741, 100.10696741, 100.10696741, 100.10696741,
       100.10696741])]
```

If you wish to save memory, you could use method `imap_unordered`:

```py
def main():
   ... # code omitted

    def compute_chunksize(iterable_size, pool_size):
        chunksize, remainder = divmod(iterable_size, 4 * pool_size)
        if remainder:
            chunksize += 1
        return chunksize

    from multiprocessing import cpu_count

    pool_size = cpu_count()
    iterable_size = 100_000 # Your best estimate
    chunksize = compute_chunksize(iterable_size, pool_size)

    with Pool(pool_size, initializer=init_pool_processes, initargs=(lookup1, matrix_data, end_dates)) as pool:
        it = pool.imap_unordered(calc, data1.itertuples(name=None, index=False), chunksize=chunksize)
        """
        # Create dictionary in memory:
        results = {cust_id: arr for cust_id, arr in it}
        """
        # Or to save memory, iterate the results:
        for cust_id, arr in it:
            print(cust_id, arr)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer,  I've tried running it on aws I get an error saying too many values to unpack. I've run it on my Mac and it works.Also I see under def init_pool_processes you have lookup1 twice, is that a typo?

Comment: On one line I declare `lookup1` as global and on the next line I set its value. I pass to `init_pool_process` via the *initargs* argument of the `Pool__init__` method 3 values so the *args* argument in `init_pool_processes` should be a tuple of 3 elements and I am unpacking it into 3 global variables. Why on AWS you get that error is a mystery to me. What do you mean by "move def(main) out"? And where do you get a broken pipe error (what environment and on what line)? Post a stack trace of any errors you get.

Comment: can you assist with my follow up question?, I have tried everything but it still takes a while to dump the file into a csv. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75360369/how-to-write-multiprocessing-results-to-csv-within-multiprocessing)